# How to display all the images uploaded to a folder in angular?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have used Node js backend to upload images to a folder called uploads which is getting uploaded successfully, now I want to display all the images uploaded there in my angular frontend application as a gallery page.

I tried introducing an array in app.component.ts to push uploaded item everytime I click the upload button, but it didn't work.

```
public imgarray=[];

  ngOnInit() {

      this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {

      file.withCredentials = false;

      this.imgarray.push('../assets/uploads/'+file);

  };
```

Comment: If you debug the results in the developer tools of your browser, what problems do occur? Also, try referring to your images just with `assets/uploads/...` without the parent path, because of virtual path handling.

Comment: `[object%20Object]:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/uploads/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)`  This was the error i get in the console. Are there any other ways to display all the images stored in a folder in Angular?

Comment: Where you create the path, you’re using + file. You probably want to use file.name